# How to count notifications with a certain status and a certain user_id?

Tags: php, mysql, database, count, notifications

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1aEi.png)
How to count notifications with a certain status and a certain user_id ?
I have some data in notification table, how is the logic to calculate notification whose status is field 3 based on user_id 2 ?
I want to issue a total of 3 notifications with a status field of 3 in user_id 2

Comment: Use `SELECT COUNT(*)` along with a `WHERE` condition that matches your criteria.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, but can you see a photo of the data in my database on the link above?
Please help...

Comment: Yes I can, but we prefer that you post data as text rather than image.

Comment: According to question guidelines, please do not use images. Convert to text instead

Comment: This is a very simple SQL query, even a beginner should be able to do it. Please show what you tried and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: Okay...
So here is my table
id,   user_id,   desc,   status
1         2         abc        3
2         2         cba        3
3         1         aaa        4
4         1         bbb       4
5         2         ddd       3

I want to count the number of notifications filed in status 3 based on user_id 2 . How to ???
Please help...

Comment: Sorry I don't really know convert mysql database image to text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
calculate notification whose status is field 3 based on user_id 2
```

According to what you asked, the where condition is status field 3 based on user_id 2.

So you can do in this way

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename WHERE status = 3 AND user_id = 2
```

Please show us your effort next time. Thank you

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very helpful for me as a beginner (y)

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for the group by function.

For all users and statuses:

```
SELECT COUNT(user_id), user_id, status FROM {Insert your table name} GROUP BY user_id, status ORDER BY user_id ASC;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very helpful for me as a beginner (y)